# Upload image fails "upload test" on localhost

Tags: uploads

starting from JS:

```
$('#logo_upload').click(function () {
            var file_data = $('#upload_image').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('upload_image', file_data);
            form_data.append('action', 'uploadImages');
            form_data.append('security', wp['security']);
            form_data.append('nome_associazione', $('.nome-associazione').html());
            form_data.append('ID', $(this).data('post'));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wp['ajaxUrl'],
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    if (error.status === 403) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
            });
        });
```

function is called correctly.

PHP:

```
public static function uploadImages() {
        self::checkAjaxReferer();
        $params = self::parseParams($_POST['params']);
        $associazione = str_replace(" ", "-", $params['nome_associazione']);
        $postID  = $params['ID'];

        if (isset($_FILES['upload_image']))
        {
                $file_name = 'logo-'.$associazione."-".$_FILES['upload_image']['name'];
                $file_size = $_FILES['upload_image']['size'];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['upload_image']['tmp_name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES['upload_image']['type'];
                $uploadedfile = $file_name;
                $upload_name = $file_name;
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

                $filepath = $uploads['path'] . "/" . $upload_name;
                if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                }

                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                $upload_overrides = array(
                    'test_form' => false
                );

                $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);

                if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])) {
                    $file = $movefile['file'];
                    $url = $movefile['url'];
                    $type = $movefile['type'];

                    // media_handle_upload( $file_handler, 0 );

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $type,
                        'post_title' => 'logo-' . $associazione,
                        'post_content' => 'Image for ' . $upload_name,
                        'post_status' => 'inherit',
                        'post_parent' => $postID
                        //'post_parent' => 0 //IF DONT WANT TO ATTACH POST ID
                    );
                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $postID);
                    //$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, 0);//IF DONT WANT TO ATTACH POST ID

                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

                    echo wp_insert_post($my_post);
                }
                else {
                         die($movefile['error']);
                }

        }
    }
```

it fails the test even being a small png image...

Comment: Where does it fail? What error is shown, if any? Are you accounting for the fact that [WordPress loads jQuery in noConflict mode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-content-1473) (ie, you need to do a bit of extra work in order to use the `$` variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one must check
-- php.ini configuration to increase max_file_size and max_upload_size

MOST IMPORTANT
on nginx.conf one must add

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 2M; /
```